# Reclassifying multiple bands in Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-maps, reclassify, geemap

I'm trying to reclassify multiple bands from my raster. It is a land use raster of the Amazon basin by Mapbiomas. I need to reclassify all 36 bands at once.

```
## Reclassifying multiple bands raster values in Google Earth Engine
#Inport amazonia mapbiomas
AmazMapbiomas = (ee.Image('projects/mapbiomas-raisg/public/collection3/mapbiomas_raisg_panamazonia_collection3_integration_v2'))
#A list of pixel values to replace.
fromList = [1, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 14, 22, 24, 25, 26, 27, 29, 30, 33, 34]
# A corresponding list of replacement values (10 becomes 1, 20 becomes 2, etc).
toList   = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 11, 6, 8, 9, 10]
#list length check if is the same length
print(len(fromList))
print(len(toList))
## Replace pixel values in the image. If the image is multi-band, only the
#here I wanted to reclassify all 36 stalls, how can I do this at once?

AmazMapbiomasReclass = img.remap({
    From: fromList,
    to: toList,
    defaultValue: 0,
    bandName: 'all'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using the Javascript API; however, it should be pretty easy to translate it to the python API. The trick is to extract the band names and map the `remap` function to each band. Then you just need to transform the list into an ImageCollection, then convert it to a multiband image and finally, rename with the original band names.

```
var bands = AmazMapbiomas.bandNames();

// Create image collection from list of images
var resul = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  // Map remap function on the list of all bands
  bands.map(function(band){
    // Remap values
    var AmazMapbiomasReclass = AmazMapbiomas.remap({
        // 'from' has to be written in lowercase
        from: fromList,
        to: toList,
        defaultValue: 0,
        // Band name according to the current band
        bandName: ee.String(band)
    });
    // Return the remapped image
    return AmazMapbiomasReclass;
  })
  // Convert from ImageCollection to multiband image
  ).toBands()
  // Rename bands to the original names
   .rename(bands);


Map.addLayer(AmazMapbiomas, {bands:'classification_2019'}, 'original');
Map.addLayer(resul, {bands:'classification_2019'}, 'reclassified');
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan! I'll try it.

Comment: the problem is that for some reason the "from" is not being recognized. Look the error:
File "<ipython-input-34-76c029fe735c>", line 55
    from: fromList,
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try defining the remapping function as: `def remapF(band):
  # Remap values
  AmazMapbiomasReclass = AmazMapbiomas.remap(fromList, toList, 0, band)
  return AmazMapbiomasReclass`